# Using AlertManager in Sametime 7.5.1

Tags: java, plugins, sametime

Based on the code [here](http://imwire.eventure.biz/imwire/articles/3.aspx) I was able to create an alert window for a specific message to be displayed on my screen. The next step for me is to show the same alert windows to specified userid (person objects) that i select based on a certain constraint. Can anybody give any pointers as to which class is to be used for this purpose. I would appreciate any help on this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i Found it here in the [IBM Sametime Forums](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/stforum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/fe75d17ca3e7f6ce85256eca005c506d?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,AnnouncementService)